# Please help with definition for outer measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The following definition is taken from page 29/Folland 's Real analysis.

[image: Outer Measure definition]

In my understanding, this definition said :  the outer measure of any set A belongs to X is the largest lower bound of the set (Let say this set is S) which contains the value of the summation of function rho (*actually this is rho not mu, that was a printing mistake, rho is the set function whose domain is the subset E of the power set of X*) for sets Ej , these sets Ej are covers for set A.

What I don't understand here is about that set S which contains those summations. Would you please show me the members which is contained in S ? Is that the { sum rho(E1 to En} , sum rho(E1 to En+1), sum rho (E1 to En+2) ,... and so on)  } . Then after I figure all the members in this set S, then I can take the largest lower bound of these members to return the outer measure right ? . Sorry for the long and silly questions. But I am new to proof based math.

Answer (score 1):

You are not reading the definition quite right.  The outer measure is the *smallest*, *upper bound* of a set, where we compute the upper bound by taking a countable collection of sets from $\mathcal{E}$ and adding their measures.

The set $S$ that you point to is a collection of real numbers, possibly including $\infty$.

The idea here is that you might have lots of sets whose measure you know—like the open interval $(a,b)$ for example, which we guess should have length $b-a$—and you are trying to come up with a good definition of measure for any set.  It is not quite possible to do this, but you can define an *outer* measure, which is the best possible upper bound for the measure of your set $A$.

So $S$ is a collection of every real number that we could possibly get when covering $A$ by sets in $\mathcal{E}$.  For example, say we want to compute $\mu^* (\mathbb{R})$ using this definition, with the measure on open intervals I mentioned earlier.  Then, for example, $(-1,1), (-2,2), (-3,3), \ldots$ is a cover of $\mathbb{R}$, and the sum of its measures is $2+4+6+\ldots = \infty$.  So in this case, $\infty$ is an element of $S$.

The "inf" on the outside means that we should take the infimum, or the least upper bound, of the real numbers in $S$.  If you play around with the example in the last paragraph, I think you'll find that $\infty$ is the only element in that set, so we come up with the intuitive result $\mu^* (\mathbb{R}) = \infty$.

Similarly, we can calculate $\mu^* ([0,1])$ by covering $[0,1]$ with the set $(-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$, which has measure $1+2\epsilon$.  Then the greatest lower bound of the set $\{1+2\epsilon \bigm| \epsilon > 0\}$ is just $1$ (though $S$ might be a little bigger than that set, so you really need to check all covers).

Comment: Thanks for help. For more depth, Let me rephrase your ans, you said that the outer measure of set A is infimum of the supremums of covers of set A. Then after that , you have a set S which contains value of those sup , then you take the inf of S. Is that correct ?

Comment: The outer measure is the infimum of some numbers.  Those numbers are the measures of certain covers of $A$.  I was being a little loose with terminology to call those covers "upper bounds"—they contain $A$, that's all that means.  "Supremum" is definitely not a good word to use here.  We take something containing $A$ (specifically, we take a collection of elements of $\mathcal{E}$ whose union contains $A$), which gives us a number, and then we take the smallest number that we can possibly get by doing this.

Comment: Ok, let me give an example and you see if it is correct or not. Let say A is covered by E1 , then rho(E1) is a x1 in R, then A is also covered by E1 U E2 , rho(E1 U E2) is x2, A is cover by E1 U E2 U E3 , then I get x3, I will continue do it to infinity. Then I get a set S= {x1,x2,....}, so outer measure of A is inf of that set S. Right ?

Comment: No, you have described one possible way of constructing a single element of $S$.

To get them all, you will also need to consider situations where, for example, $E_1$ does not cover $A$, $E_1 \cup E_2$ does not cover $A$, etc., but only the infinite union $\bigcup_i E_i$ covers $A$.  And then you need to take the infinite sum $\sum_j \mu(E_j)$, which is, again, one element of the set $S$.

Comment: Actually, what you described is not even an element of $S$.  You described a cover $\{x_1, x_2,\ldots\}$, but the associated element of $S$ is $\sum_{i=j}^\infty \mu (x_j)$.  Remember, each element of $S$ is a non-negative real number.

Comment: I am currently teaching from this book.  I would not recommend it for someone who is new to writing mathematical proofs, as it has almost no easy exercises, and leaves out most of the motivation for the technical work (which Folland assumes that you know from previous analysis courses).  You obviously know your situation better than I do, but I thought I should mention my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for help, you are right, I am a newbie in proof based math, the only formal course in analysis I have is using Bartle - intro analysis book. However Folland is my school textbook for the Measure 1 and 2 classes , thus I have no choice but to work hard.

Comment: Back to my example, which means the element of S is the infinite sum of cover that is the union of {Ej} j = 1 to infinity right ? And you will have many many cases of infinite covers , like {E'j} is another one.

Comment: No, once again, the only elements of $S$ are real numbers.  There are too many possible permutations of ideas here to simply guess; you need to find some way of knowing what you are talking about very precisely.  Try working backwards, or try working forwards, or try unpacking the definition onto 10 sheets of paper on an empty desk.  But don't just throw words together.  You are correct that there are many covers, but you need to be able to explain, clearly and correctly, exactly how you will extract a real number from such a thing, or else it will not be possible to do even one book problem.

Comment: What I really meant previously is that you will get the result from those sum which is a real number as u said. In order to get those number, you will use the function $\rho$ to get the value of each individual Ej then add them up. Thanks for helping me so much for my silly question. Please forgive my ignorance in high-level math ^_^.